# how to open app directly from deeplink without user intervention

Tags: ios, deep-linking

If we do the deep linking in iOS, when user goes to that specific url it show open app on top and then user has to click it.

How to automatically open app when he goes to that url ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use universal links in iOS.

you can find a detailed tutorial [here](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/universal-links-in-ios-79c4ee038272)

Comment: Nice doc there, one thing I don't understand is https://zomato.com & https://www.zomato.com opens Zomato app, but https://myntra.com doesn't open Myntra app but https://www.myntra.com opens Myntra app, any idea why ?

Comment: That is probably just the way their apple app association file is written. check the tutorial to know about apple app association file

Comment: It all depends on your app association file and URL scheme configuration on the iOS app, if my answer has solved your query then, please mark it as an accepted solution.

Comment: @AkashSoni 

https://www.zomato.com/apple-app-site-association

https://www.myntra.com/apple-app-site-association

Here are both and I don't find any difference in these files